# How do you test if a matrix exists in a matrix list? (Wordle Project)

Tags: r, list, matrix, wordle-game

I am an infrequent R users so my apologies if any of my terminology is incorrect. I am working on a project around the game Wordle to see if a given Wordle submission in my family group chat is unique or if they have already been submitted before. The inspiration for this came from the twitter account "Scorigami" which tracks every NFL game and tweets whether or not that score has occurred before in the history of the league.

To load the Wordle entries into R, I've decided to turn each submission into a Matrix where 0 = incorrect letter, 1 = right letter/wrong position, and 2 = right letter/correct position. In R this looks like this:

```
wordle_brendan <- rbind(c(1,0,0,0,0),c(2,2,0,0,0),c(2,2,0,0,0),c(2,2,2,2,2))
wordle_jack <- rbind(c(2,0,0,0,0),c(2,2,0,0,0),c(2,2,2,2,2))
```

I then combine them into a list that will be used to check against any future Wordle submissions to see if they have been previously submitted.

```
list <- list(wordle_brendan, wordle_jack)
```

I think I am on the right track, but I don't know how to create a new wordle matrix to test whether that submission has been given before. Say I recreated "wordle_brendan" with the same values but under a different name... How would I then get R to check if that matrix exists in my preexisting list of matrices? I've tried using the %in% function 1,000 different ways but can't get it to work.. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks! (And if you can think of a better way to do this, please let me know!)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do this, but this is pretty simple. We need some samples to check:

```
new1 <- list[[2]]   # The same as your second matrix
new2 <- new1
new2[3, 5] <- 0     # Change one position from 2 to 0.
```

To compare

```
any(sapply(list, identical, y=new1))
# [1] TRUE
any(sapply(list, identical, y=new2))
# [1] FALSE
```

So `new1` matches an existing matrix, but `new2` does not. To see which matrix:

```
which(sapply(list, identical, y=new1))
# [1] 2
which(sapply(list, identical, y=new2))
# integer(0)
```

So `new1` matches the second matrix in `list`, but `new2` does not match any matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way with a `matequal` function. Base function `identical` compares objects, not values and if the matrices have the same values but different attributes, such as names, `identical` returns FALSE.

This is many times too strict. A function that compares values only will return TRUE in these cases.

I will use [dcarlson's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73873999/8245406) `new1` to illustrate this point.

```r
matequal <- function(x, y) {
  ok <- is.matrix(x) && is.matrix(y) && all(dim(x) == dim(y))
  ok && all(x == y)
}

wordle_brendan <- rbind(c(1,0,0,0,0),c(2,2,0,0,0),c(2,2,0,0,0),c(2,2,2,2,2))
wordle_jack <- rbind(c(2,0,0,0,0),c(2,2,0,0,0),c(2,2,2,2,2))
list <- list(wordle_brendan, wordle_jack)
new1 <- list[[2]]   # The same as your second matrix

wordle_john <- wordle_jack
dimnames(wordle_john) <- list(1:3, letters[1:5])
list2 <- list(wordle_brendan, wordle_jack, wordle_john)

sapply(list2, identical, y=new1)
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE

sapply(list2, matequal, y=new1)
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

`identical` is not a function to compare two objects' values, it's a function to compare the objects themselves. In the following example `identical` returns FALSE though `x` and `y` have equal values, in the usual sense of equal.

```r
matequal <- function(x, y) {
  ok <- is.matrix(x) && is.matrix(y) && all(dim(x) == dim(y))
  ok && all(x == y)
}

x <- matrix(1:5, ncol = 1)
y <- matrix(1 + 0:4, ncol = 1)

all(x == y)
#> [1] TRUE

identical(x, y)
#> [1] FALSE

matequal(x, y)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

This is because the internal representations of `x` and `y`, borrowed from the C language, correspond to different class attributes. One of the objects stores elements of class `"integer"` and the other elements of class `"numeric"`. The matrices both have the same class attribute (`"matrix" "array"`), the matrices elements' storage type is the main difference.

In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73873405/how-do-you-test-if-a-matrix-exists-in-a-matrix-list-wordle-project/73874075?noredirect=1#comment130443882_73874075) it is asked

> Thank you and dcarlson for the response! Regarding the your two sapply lines, can you explain what the use would be behind using matequal as opposed to identical? Is the only difference that matequal takes into account the column and row names?

So the answer to the question in comment is no, the attributes, in this case `dimnames`, are not the only reason why `identical` is some or many times not ideal to compare R objects.

```r
typeof(x)
#> [1] "integer"
typeof(y)
#> [1] "double"

class(x[1])
#> [1] "integer"
class(y[2])
#> [1] "numeric"

class(x)
#> [1] "matrix" "array"
class(y)
#> [1] "matrix" "array"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you and dcarlson for the response! Regarding the your two sapply lines, can you explain what the use would be behind using matequal as opposed to identical?  Is the only difference that matequal takes into account the column and row names?

Comment: Maybe I should've read your description first... :)

Comment: @LiamBrothers `identical` can be misleading, see the edit.